# when the answer is always found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

why is the console output is always found? any email or passwords i enter, the output is the same, even if they are not in the database

```
 app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

    const email = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password


    User.find({ email: email, password: password }, function(err, userInfo) {
        if (err) {

            console.log("err")
        } else {
            if (userInfo) {
                console.log("found")
            } else {
                console.log("not found")
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: can you `console.log(userInfo)` in else?

Comment: This may be possible that DB may not be throwing an exception for `No record found`. And you may be getting userInfo as an empty array or empty object which resolves to True in javascript.

Comment: Why are you using condition if(userInfo) as you are checking for the error above, Remove that condition and check whether the `userInfo.length > 0`

Comment: @MDMNauman, what do you mean, i am checking if there's an err  there otherwise, it should display found or not found

Comment: @Zaid Yes, you are checking but when you are using find() it will always return an array so this condition will be useless instead check `userInfo.length > 0`

Comment: @MDMNauman hmm, got it, thanks, it's working now! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because User.find will return an array, even if there is no document matching your query it will return an empty array.

And in javascript, if you pass empty array in if the condition it passes

Use **User.findOne** or check **if (userInfo.length > 0)**

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

const email = req.body.username
const password = req.body.password


User.findOne({ email: email, password: password }, function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {

        console.log("err")
    } else {
        if (userInfo) {
            console.log("found")
        } else {
            console.log("not found")
        }
    }
});
})
```